# Obtaining info about java crash

Tags: java, diagnostics, jvm-crash

I am launching swing java application that is heavily instrumented by my javaagent. The agent is really complex, it performs some subtle instrumentations, and java simply crashes after some time after launch. I can see in the log of my agent - it instruments/retransforms classes and so on, but suddenly java just halts *with no traces and no error messages*.

I want to find reasons of the crash, so I have done the following:

- added the shutdown hook int agent that simple prints "ERROR!"
- set DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler into agent that simple prints "ERROR!"
- surrounded the body of agent's premain method with try/catch block, that catches Throwable and prints "ERROR!"
- added to command line -XX:+ShowMessageBoxOnError -XX:OnError="echo ERROR!" -XX:ErrorFile="C:\path here\java_error%p.log"
- assured, that the main method of target swing app is also surrounded with try-catch-throwable

All these actions didn't help. Application fails on startup (there are no logs of target application yet), but there is *no* message box, *no* error file, *no* "ERROR!" messages in console - i.e., absolutely *no* information and *no* sign of the crash.

What am I doing wrong? :) How can I get any information about this crash?

Comment: do you run the app using java.exe or javaw.exe? Perhaps there's something logged to the console if java.exe is used?

Comment: I launch "java -javaagent ... -jar ..." from win cmd. No messages in console at all. Simply halts.

Comment: research how to generate jvm core dump

Comment: @hovanessyan, what exactly do you mean? I've tested forementioned -XX options on sample app, that forces JVM crash (taken [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1239584)), and they work as expected. Also core dump is printed to the console.
Also I can generate the core dump manually using Ctrl+Break, but I need it to be generated at java halt.